Change Ceedling output of failures for eclipse to jump directly to it
I managed to start Ceedling as a c-build project and the complete log is written to the console window.
I also created an error parser, which works for the most of the warning/errors.
But for the summary list of failure test, I found no way to extract the information for Eclipse to directly jump to the line of error.
One reason was, that line, failure reason and file information was not written to a single console line. This I could solve. But the second problem is that only the test file name is written without any path information, and this is not enough for Eclipse.
I tried to add the path info, but unfortunately I have no experience with ruby so it's difficult for me.
Can someone help me? Or is there a better solution using Ceedling in Eclipse that is already available, without writing my own error parser?
Find attached the output and the code snippet:

And the output:


Did you take a look at the following tutorial: https://www.throwtheswitch.org/eclipse

It appears all the result data is aggregated Here maybe try using a different Hash key like hash[:results][:source][:file]
